# F# Interactiveで指定した型の宣言を調べたい

Tags: f#

F# Interactiveでは値と一緒に型も表示してくれます。

```
> 1;;
val it : int = 1
> Some 1;;
val it : int option = Some 1
> printf;;
val it : (Printf.TextWriterFormat<'a> -> 'a) = <fun:clo@1>
```

では、型を指定してその型の宣言を調べる方法はないでしょうか？

単純に型名だけを指定すると、コンストラクタの型が表示されてしまいます。

```
> Printf.TextWriterFormat<_>;;
val it : arg00:string -> PrintfFormat<'a,System.IO.TextWriter,unit,unit> =
  <fun:clo@5-1>
> Option<_>;;

  Option<_>;;
  ^^^^^^

stdin(7,1): error FS0039: 値またはコンストラクター 'Option' が定義されていません
```

そうではなく、.fsi ファイルに書くような、型自体の宣言が見たいのです。

F# Interactive上で型を定義したときには似たようなものが表示されるので、これを既存の型にも適用できないものでしょうか。

```
> type Foo = A of int | B with
-     member self.Hoge(x) = 1;;

type Foo =
  | A of int
  | B
  with
    member Hoge : x:'a -> int
  end
```

関数の型が気になったときにF# Interactiveに入力するだけでわかるように、型の宣言も同じように調べられたらブラウザ開かずに済むのになと・・・。

Answer (score 2):

回答になっているかわかりませんが、F# interactiveでなくF#プロジェクトであればF12 Go To Definitionはブラウザーでドキュメントを開いたりしますが、Alt+F12 Peek Definitionならエディタ上に型定義を表示してくれます。

Answer (score 0):

ちょっと違うのかもしれないですが（定義に関してはソースを見る必要があるかと思います）、
多分、`typeof`  のことかなと思います。

`typeof<型>`のように使います。

例：`typeof<Option<_>>;;`

Comment: そのTypeからF#の型定義の表記で出せないものか、というところなのですが、メソッドの宣言ぐらいならType型の出力をそのまま読むのも手ではありますね。

Comment: とりあえず`Option`のような場合(既存の型の属するモジュール名が分かっていれば) `Option.`タブ補完。`> Option.Some;; val it : 'a -> 'a option = <fun:clo@1>` のように表示できますけど。